# Most straightforward way of getting a raw, unparsed HTTPS response

Tags: curl, https

What would be the most straightforward way of making a GET request to a url over HTTPS, and getting the raw, unparsed response?

Could this be achieved with curl? If so, what options would you need to use?

Answer (score 83):

If you want to use `curl`, this should work:

```
curl -D - https://www.google.com/
```

Note, however, that this is not exactly the raw response. For instance [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) will not be visible in the response. Using `--raw` solves this, also verbose mode (`-v`) is useful, too and `-i` shows the headers before the response body:

```
curl -iv --raw https://www.google.com/
```

If you want to use a pager like less on the result, it is also necessary to disable the progress-bar (`-s`):

```
curl -ivs --raw https://www.google.com/ | less
```

Depending on what you want to do this may or may not be a problem.

What you do get is all HTTP response headers and the document at the requested URL.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple way that comes to mind

```
echo 'GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com

' | openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: note that some servers (e.g github.com) only work with `HTTP/1.0`

Comment: I have a question based on your answer. Please check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622274/why-does-echo-works-but-cat-does-not-when-pipeing-to-openssl

Answer (score 7):

It's not `curl`, but it should be available on almost all Unices:

```
wget -S --spider https://encrypted.site
```

If the status messages bother you:

```
wget -S --spider https://encrypted.site 2>&1 | awk '/^  /'
```

If you want CRLF line endings:

```
wget -S --spider https://encrypted.site 2>&1 | awk '/^  / { sub(/$/,"\r"); print }'
```

Comment: Do you know if this would preserve the `\r\n` characters in the response?

Comment: @Acorn - First of all, not all webservers will respond with `\r\n` as a line ending. I don't believe this will preserve it in any case, but if that matters to you, I'll add a way of getting that result in the answer.

Comment: any idea how to parse the response headers in a { json: "object" } ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ GET -e https://www.google.com
```

On Debian/Ubuntu distros belongs to the package `lwp-request`.