# why does `echo` works but `cat` does not when pipeing to `openssl`

Tags: bash, command-line

I was looking at [Most straightforward way of getting a raw, unparsed HTTPS response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29406/206574) to make a GET request to a url over HTTPS, and receive the raw, unparsed response.

the following works:

```
echo 'GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com

' | openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null
```

However, I want to put the request in a text file and `cat` it to the command.

So I created `raw-http.txt`

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: google.com
```

Just to be clear, there is a blank like after `Host: google.com`.

Now when I try:

```
cat raw-http.txt | openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null
```

it just freezes for a long time then respond `^X%`.

why `echo` is working here but `cat` not. what can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is a blank like after

There should be two.

```bsh
$ echo '"'; cat raw.txt; echo '"'
"
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: google.com    

"
$ cat raw.txt | openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

As for your `echo` example it has an extra unneeded newline, so this will work:

```bsh
echo 'GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
' | openssl s_client -quiet -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Consider `nl` to help demonstrate blank lines

Comment: do you have any idea why it is responding `301 Move` instead of the proper website?

Comment: Google wants people to land on `www.google.com` instead of `google.com`